# R - reclassify by intervals while giving 0 its own class

Tags: r, intervals, cut

I have a table with a Percent Change column, and I am trying to reclassify the data into quartiles while preserving a separate category for all data that has not changed (i.e. Percent Change value of 0)

I have Percent Change data ranging from -0.5 to 1, I am trying to reclassify it so that I have 7 categories: -0.5 - -0.26, -0.25 - -0.01, 0, 0.01 - 0.24, 0.25 - 0.49, 0.5 - 0.74, 0.74 - 1

Using `cut()` doesn't let me specify 0 as its own class.

```
forestareamap$Interval <- cut(forestareamap$PercentChange, breaks = c(-0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1))
```

I'm a beginner with R, could anyone point me in the right direction how I could reclassify this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 forestareamap$Interval <-
           cut(forestareamap$PercentChange, 
               breaks = c(0, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1),
               right=TRUE, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

The default behavior of cut is to have open intervals on the right. Setting that to FALSE and adding include lowest=TRUE should 'deliver the goods'.